# How to fix the "if" always going "true"

Tags: java, if-statement

I have written a script for the left rotation in java and I have used 2 for loops in the code.

I have used if the condition for checking the first iteration in the 2nd loop and then some processing in it. I am passing 2 arguments "a" is an array and "d" is no of rotation.

```
static int[] rotLeft(int[] a, int d) {
    int temp1 = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int j;
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        for(j = a.length - 1; j > 0; j--){
            if(j == a.length - 1){
                temp1 = a[0];
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = temp1;
            }
            else{
                temp1 = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }                
    }
    return a;
}
```

But the problem it goes true for each iteration. I know I am doing some stupid mistake.

Comment: I suspect you intend there to be `{}` around your `else` block.

Comment: You have two lines indented after your `else`, but only one of them is part of the `if/else` statement.

Comment: how about executing everything in your if block outside of the for block (without if), and all the following cases in an iteration? there is no need for an if here.

Comment: What Tobias is trying to tell you: this code is really really hard to read and understand. It starts with nothing telling variable names like `a` or `d`.

Comment: Guys thank you for pointing out brace mistake after else but the main issue is still persistent.

Answer (score 2):

```
        else
            temp1 = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
```

I suspect you mean:

```
        else {
            temp1 = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
```

Whitespace has no semantic meaning in Java (unlike a small number of other languages, like Python).

Comment: @apoorva-sharma TIP: To avoid problems like this, is highly encouraged to correctly indent your code. Indentation exists for a reason.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I would recommend using a formatting tool, rather than just saying "you should do something correctly" - after all, who does it incorrectly on purpose?

Comment: @AndyTurner "who does it incorrectly on purpose?" — people who don't think it matters.

Comment: @khelwood they still don't (presumably) intend to write incorrect code.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't like formatting tools. I prefer to waste a bit of time by taking into account that I should indent correctly when I code. You know that now is automatic, but when you are a newbie, you don't put anough attention into it. When I started, I remember the exact time when I decided to put more effort into indenting correctly instead of just adding lines of code. I think that "don't understimate indentation and waste time with that" is a good tip.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález my point is that if you have no point of reference as to what is "correct", you could simply be putting effort into make things consistently wrong.

Comment: @AndyTurner well, I'm not going to add a manual here, but we all know what "correct indentation" is, and if you don't know, go Google. Was just a small comment/tip, not a full StackOverflow answer. I'm not going to say "a tab after each curly, etc" in a comment... just Google it xD Also, autoindentators don't teach you nothing, specially when you don't put attention into it. You just see that formatting happens and move into the next line of code without paying attention. The key here is to pay attention to indent correctly. If you don't know how to indent, is upon you how you learn do that.

Comment: But yes, I'm going to add to the tip. "If you don't know how to indent, I recommend you to go for an autoformatter and see what it outputs". Specially the part where "see what it outputs", don't be lazy haha.